# maven shaded plugin shade string literal in my code

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

It is weird that maven shaded plugin change the string literal in my source code, but didn't shaded the class name (because I exclude it in relocation)

This is the orignal string in my source code,

```
"com.mycompany.ClassA"
```

after shade it becomes

```
"com.mycompanay.shaded.com.mycompany.ClassA"
```

BTW, I use maven-shaded-plugin 3.2.4

Comment: How is the string declared and used? Are you sure it's the Shade plugin? I wasn't aware it did anything like that

Comment: Also what version of shade plugin are you using?

Comment: my plugin version is 3.2.4